# react-router-dom + outlet context - which type for context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I don't know which types I should add to context  `const context: any = useOutletContext();` at the moment I added ':any', but which will correct types?

Additionaly when I found more information about types for context?

Below files:

- BooksLayout.tsx

```
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export function BooksLayout() {
  return (
    <>
      <Outlet context={{ hello: "world" }} />
    </>
  );
}
```

- Book.tsx

```
import { useOutletContext, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export function Book() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const context: any = useOutletContext();

  return (
    <h1>
      Book {id} {context.hello}
    </h1>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an interface for your context:

```
interface BookOutletContext {
  hello: string
}
```

2. Add the `satisfies` keyword to your Outlet for type safety:

```
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export function BooksLayout() {
  return (
    <>
      <Outlet context={{ hello: "world" } satisfies BookOutletContext} />
    </>
  );
}
```

3. When using the context, use `BookOutletContext` as the generic type in `useOutletContext`:

```
import { useOutletContext, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export function Book() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const context = useOutletContext<BookOutletContext>();

  return (
    <h1>
      Book {id} {context.hello}
    </h1>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface that matches what you are providing the Context.

```
interface BookContext {
  hello: string;
}
```

...

```
function Book() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const context: BookContext = useOutletContext();

  return (
    <h1>
      Book {id} {context.hello}
    </h1>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-outlet-context-which-type-for-context]